# Convolution of continuous compactly supported functions on étale groupoid is continuous

Tags: c-star-algebras, groupoids, continuity

Let $G$ be an étale Hausdorff groupoid, i.e. a topological groupoid $G$ such that the source and range maps $s,r: G \to G$ are local homeomorphisms.

Consider the complex vector space $C_c(G)$ of compactly supported continuous functions $G \to \mathbb{C}$.

Given $f,g\in C_c(G)$, we define their convolution by
$$(f\star g)(\gamma):= \sum_{\alpha \beta = \gamma} f(\alpha)g(\beta).$$

I see that this is well-defined because there are only finitely many composable $(\alpha, \beta)$ with $f(\alpha)g(\beta)\ne 0$ due to the source and range maps being local homeomorphisms.

I also see that $\operatorname{supp}(f\star g)$ is a compact subset, as it is contained in the compact subset $\operatorname{supp}(f)\operatorname{supp}(g)$. However, why is $f\star g: G \to \mathbb{C}$ a continuous map?

Comment: It should be similar to the well-definedness: given $\gamma$, we could find finitely many continuous maps $\gamma'\mapsto\alpha_i$ and $\gamma'\mapsto\beta_i$ for $\gamma'$ in a neighborhood of $\gamma$ such that, for every $\gamma'$, we have $\alpha_i\beta_i=\gamma'$ and they enumerate all $\alpha,\beta$ lying in the support of $f,g$ and $\alpha\beta=\gamma'$.

Comment: @Z.M Can you please give a little more details (and possibly write an answer?)?

Comment: By a partition of unity argument, you can write every $f\in C_c(G)$ as a linear combination of functions that are supported on open bisections. Using this it's easy to check that the convolution is continuous.

Comment: @JamieGabe Thanks! I think your idea works! I will write an answer.